# Run 2 different piece code through Javascript depending on screen width (on the fly)?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 sets of javascript code. One is for normal (desktop view) and the other one will be used for mobile devices (and anything lower than 500px).

This is the piece of javascript for normal (desktop view):

```
var sliderProductNames = [
{foreach $products as $product}
    "{$product.name}",
{/foreach}
];
```

And this is the piece of javascript I have for mobile devices:

```
var sliderProductNames = [
{foreach $products as $product}
    "{$product.name|replace:'Brandname ':''}",
{/foreach}
];
```

As you can see, what I am trying to achieve here, is that it removes a part of text for mobile devices. So it will make things look less 'cluttered'.

Is it possible to run the first piece of javascript, unless the window is resized or visited with a mobile device (say anyhing less than 480px in width).

And can javascript change this on the fly (as in resizing window)?

It's from WHMCS which uses Smarty templates, but can I run both pieces of code depending on screen width through javascript detection?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know what that is, but it's not JavaScript.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it looks like Moustache, a template language - which in the end will output runable html/JS I guess. This doesn't seem like a very good solution, however. I would separate those two data columns and use CSS to display or hide certain bits, which will happen on the fly without you ever having to worry about it.

Comment: if angular allowed `http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/`

Comment: Sorry, can't use AngularJS. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without jQuery, take a look at [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
   /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

In case you need to react whenever the screen is resized do not forget to check the  [returned object of matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and you can

```js
    var sliderProductNames = '';
    $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        sliderProductNames = '[{foreach $products as $product}"{$product.name|replace:\"Brandname \":\"\"}",{/foreach}]';
      } else {
        sliderProductNames = '[{foreach $products as $product}"{$product.name}",{/foreach}]';
      }
      $('#txtarea').append(sliderProductNames + "<br>");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=txtarea></div>
```

Comment: If use that, I get a blank page? Apparently it's not working, or I am doing something wrong. :(

Comment: Are you running the code snippet? use full page and resize window